# warning in uitableview

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I complied using iOS 4.1 for uitableview program. What has to be done ?

> WARNING: Using legacy cell layout due
>   to delegate implementation of
>   tableView:accessoryTypeForRowWithIndexPath:
>   in .  Please
>   remove your implementation of this
>   method and set the cell properties
>   accessoryType and/or
>   editingAccessoryType to move to the
>   new cell layout behavior.  This method
>   will no longer be called in a future
>   release.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do exactly what the warning message says: remove the implementation of `tableView:accessoryTypeForRowWithIndexPath:` and set the cell's `accessoryType` and `editingAccessoryType` in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` instead.

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation of `tableView:accessoryTypeForRowWithIndexPath`:

> (Deprecated in iOS 3.0. Use the accessory-view and accessory-type properties (for both normal and editing modes) of the UITableViewCell class when configuring table-view cells.)