# Legacy cell layout?

Tags: ios, uitableview, cell

I am getting this in my console, what does it mean and how can I fix it?

> 2011-07-18 22:08:31.004 App[4176:707] WARNING: Using legacy cell layout due to delegate implementation of tableView:accessoryTypeForRowWithIndexPath: in <Settings: 0x250c60>.  Please remove your implementation of this method and set the cell properties accessoryType and/or editingAccessoryType to move to the new cell layout behavior.  This method will no longer be called in a future release.

Edit: This is iOS and here is the method:

```
    - (UITableViewCellAccessoryType)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView accessoryTypeForRowWithIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    switch (indexPath.row) {

        case 2:
            return UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
            break;

        case 3:
            return UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
            break;

        case 4:
            return UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
            break;

    }
    return UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
}
```

Comment: I'm assuming this is ios? Please show the code in that method. Try this link http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/DeprecationAppendix/AppendixADeprecatedAPI.html

Comment: It looks like this question was answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3978707/warning-in-uitableview

Comment: yep, I fixed it thanks to the answerer below :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means that you are implementing a deprecated method, and the system is using a backwards-compatibility mode because of it.

You should do exactly what the message suggests: remove your implementation of `tableView:accessoryTypeForRowWithIndexPath:`, and instead assign the appropriate values to the `accessoryType` and/or `editingAccessoryType` properties instead.