# legacy cell layout due to delegate implementation of tableView

Tags: iphone, ipad, uitableview

WARNING: Using legacy cell layout due to delegate implementation of `tableView:accessoryTypeForRowWithIndexPath:` in `<Settings: 0x250c60>`. Please remove your implementation of this method and set the cell properties accessoryType and/or `editingAccessoryType` to move to the new cell layout behavior.

Answer (score 2):

Here,
`accessoryTypeForRowWithIndexPath` is deprecated in iPhone OS 3.0.

Instead set like this.

```
cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton;
```

Existed Answers - [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6741551/legacy-cell-layout)